Is out-of-scope local variables' memory reused?
struct Big { char data[5000]; };

extern int some_input;

int main() {
    switch (some_input) {
    case 0: {
        struct Big big;
        big.data[0] = 0; // just try to do something
        return big.data[0];
    } break;
    case 1: {
        struct Big big;
        big.data[1] = 1;
        return big.data[1];
    } break;
    case 2: {
        struct Big big;
        big.data[2] = 2;
        return big.data[2];
    } break;
    case 3: {
        struct Big big;
        big.data[3] = 3;
        return big.data[3];
    } break;
    case 4: {
        struct Big big;
        big.data[4] = 4;
        return big.data[4];
    } break;
    }
    return 0;
}

I suppose 5000 bytes is enough for main(), but Visual studio 2022 reported: "Warning C6262 Function uses '25000' bytes of stack. Consider moving some data to heap."
Does that mean out-of-scope local variables' memory is not reused?

Did you enable compiler optimizations?

"Is out-of-scope local variables' memory reused?" The C standard doesn't specify such things. It's a matter of implementation. One compiler may reuse, another may not. A specific compiler may reuse with some compiler options while not doing it with other options.

Note that you have big.data[2]; when you presumably wanted return big.data[2];  Without the return, it's just an expression statement that would most likely be optimized away since it serves no purpose.  The other cases don't have this problem.

@SouravGhosh This is an IDE warning which doesn't seem to be affected by actual optimizations.

Have a look here: godbolt.com comparison of gcc and msvc (Edit: I had to add a parameter to the switch-statement to prevent full optimization, but I think think this was an issue with the minimum code example)
It actually looks like this is only an issue in msvc (the Microsoft compiler). GCC behaves as expected and only uses 5k of stack.
GCC:
mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-5004], 4

MSVC:
tv64 = -25008                                     ; size = 4
_big$1 = -25004                               ; size = 5000
_big$2 = -20004                               ; size = 5000
_big$3 = -15004                               ; size = 5000
_big$4 = -10004                               ; size = 5000
_big$5 = -5004                                      ; size = 5000

PS: You may try some optimizations, using /O2 will optimize the code and < 100 Bytes remain in this example in msvc.

The expected behavior of the compiler with optimizations enabled is to replace this whole dead code with return 0; and not allocate anything.

What Godbolt proves here is that the compiler behaves like that for this and only this example. That's actually not very useful to know.

This answer is great. Dunno why it's downvoted...

@Erciyuanshagou - Some people might not like it being called "an issue" that the compiler generates code exactly as written. If you don't ask it to optimize, it doesn't. That might help you recognize the code in the debugger.

Not my down vote, but the godbolt example shows a different, modified code than the one in the question. And MSVC doesn't give the supposed diagnostic message either so I wonder if it comes from the compiler, probably not but from a static analyser. Intelnonsense-somesuch?

Yes, I forgot to mention, that I had intorduce the paramter for the switch statement in godbolt, but this modified code does show the different behaviour in gcc and msvc.
